# MySQLInstaller popping up unexpectedly

Tags: windows-10, mysql

Often, my Windows **cmd** randomly opens and executes MySQL Installer. It runs about 1 second and then it shuts off immediately. Since execution is really fast, it has been hard to capture it. Today though, I managed to capture a screenshot, while it was executing:

[image: MYSQLInstaller]

I fail to understand why this is happening. This process seems to be asynchronous.(It doesn't happen at a specific time, nor is it related to any task I'm doing)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is simply a task that is scheduled with Windows **Task Scheduler** per applicable options (likely the defaults) that keeps the [MySQL Product Catalog](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installer/en/mysql-installer-catalog-dashboard.html) updated with the latest updates and such.

Please note that this does not automatically install the updates onto the MySQL server but it gets the [MySQL Product Catalog](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installer/en/mysql-installer-catalog-dashboard.html) updated so you can install applicable component updates if needed.

### What is it

> **Product Catalog**
>
> The product catalog stores the complete list of released MySQL
>   products for Microsoft Windows that are available to download from
>   MySQL. By default, and when an Internet connection is present,
>   [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/) Installer updates the catalog
>   daily. You can also update the catalog manually from the dashboard
>
> **MySQL Installer Dashboard**
>
> 2. The MySQL Installer Options button ([image]) enables you to schedule daily
>      automatic catalog updates. By default, catalog updates are scheduled
>      at the hour when MySQL Installer was first installed. When new
>      products or product versions are available, MySQL Installer adds them
>      to the catalog and then displays an arrow icon ([image]) next to the
>      version number of installed products listed in the dashboard.
>
>    Use this option to enable or disable automatic catalog updates and to
>      reset the time of day when the MySQL Installer updates the catalog
>      automatically. For specific settings, see the task named
>      ManifestUpdate in the Windows Task Scheduler.
>
> ---
>
> 5. The **`Catalog`** link enables you to download the latest catalog of MySQL products manually and then to integrate those product changes
>      with MySQL Installer. The catalog-download action does not perform an
>      upgrade of the products already installed on the host. Instead, it
>      returns to the dashboard and displays an arrow icon in the Version
>      column for each installed product that has a newer version. Use the
>      **`Upgrade`** operation to install the newer product version.
>
> [source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installer/en/mysql-installer-catalog-dashboard.html)

### Check it manually

You can run this update from an admin elevated command prompt using the same path as in the scheduled task (see below **How to disable it**) including passed arguments to see what updates are available per this check (e.g. `"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Installer for Windows\MySQLInstallerConsole.exe" Community Update`).

[image]

### How to disable it

Simply go to the **Task Scheduler** and disable the job named **ManifestUpdate** which should be located in the **Installer** container beneath the **MySQL** container which is just beneath **Task Scheduler Library**; just right click and select **Disable**.

[image]
[image][image]

---

### Further Resources

- [MySQL Installer Product Catalog](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installer/en/mysql-installer-catalog-dashboard.html)
- [MySQLInstallerConsole Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installer/en/MySQLInstallerConsole.html)